# Unable to use xml formatted launch files with ROS2 eloquent

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a launch file in the xml format to launch using `ros2 launch launch_files launch_file.xml` however when I do so I receive the error `[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): The launch file may have a syntax error, or its format is unknown`. I have modeled the launch file off of the ones found in the demo_examples_cpp package, using the exact same code as the [talker.listener.launch.xml](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/df9a85e41737b65a04cf2c8c4357bea71ae85384/demo_nodes_cpp/launch/topics/talker_listener.launch.xml)
 example. I have checked to make sure the file ended up in the share installation folder with my .launch.py files. The .launch.py files work fine. I have also tried passing in the entire path to the ros2 launch command without luck. Any guidance toward getting the XML launch files to work would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349170/unable-to-use-xml-formatted-launch-files-with-ros2-eloquent/) by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-12**:
@mequi: please always use permalinks when linking to artefacts on Github/Bitbucket/etc. Otherwise we run the risk of your links going stale after some time, reducing the value of your question (and any potential answer).

I've replaced the link to `talker.listener.launch.xml` with a permalink, but please keep it mind next time.

**Comment by [Bastien Taillandier](https://answers.ros.org/users/53865/bastien-taillandier/) on 2020-04-22**:
Uppp ! I get the same problem, I don't suceed to use xml launch file with ros2 eloquent ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same exact problem. It seems that no package in the [ros2 variants](https://github.com/ros2/variants) depends on launch_xml or launch_yaml (ros2launch, the only launch related dependency, does not for some reason) so they are not installed with the debian packages. You have to install it manually

```
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-launch-xml
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-launch-yaml
```

This worked for me

edit: They fixed it in the github repo, so you will no longer need to separately need to install extra packages in the next ROS2 version or next eloquent patch.

edit2: As of 29 October 2020, this was fixed in foxy, but you still need to do the above for eloquent

---

Originally posted by [Thodoris Tyrovouzis](https://answers.ros.org/users/54346/thodoris-tyrovouzis/) with karma: 76 on 2020-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2